# Power BI - Calculation group does not produce the same output as measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

In the [following Power BI file](https://allibertoffice-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/frederi_rose_allibert_net/ESMcOHn12TROmPsGmz4lb2UB7xl1Sbvjt-kLSsQRf3EFvw?e=mDOJX4), I have defined a calculation group **'CG - Last days'[Name] = "5 last days"** as follow :

```
VAR tbl_FILTER =
        TOPN(
            10
        ,   dim_DATES
        ,   dim_DATES[Date]
        ,   DESC
        )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SELECTEDMEASURE()
    ,   KEEPFILTERS( tbl_FILTER )
    )
```

My problem is it does not produce the expected output :
filtering on the 10 most recent dates of a date table with only January and February should return a count of 10 dates only for the month of February ; but that is not what I get :
[image]
If anyone knows why, I am all ears.

Comment: Can you share a .pbix with minimum reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem here is that calculation items don't modify just any DAX expression, only measure references. Try defining a count measure `COUNT( dim_DATES_2[dat_DATE] )` and using that in your test instead.

Please see this article: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-calculation-groups/

In particular, this part

> The application of a calculation item replaces a measure reference with the expression of the calculation item, still applying an implicit context transition. Focus your attention on this sentence: *A measure reference is replaced*. Without a measure reference, a calculation item does not apply any modification. For example, the following code is not affected by any calculation item because it does not contain any measure reference:
>
> ```
> CALCULATE (
>    SUMX ( Sales, Sales[Quantity] * Sales[Net Price] ),
>    'Time Intelligence'[Time calc] = "YTD"
> )
> ```

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, you also need to use `ALL(dim_DATES)` instead of `dim_Dates` inside the `TOPN`. This is because the `dim_Dates` has filter context applied to it from the visual, so only includes February dates in the February row and Januari dates in the Januari row. `ALL` removes this filter context and returns the top dates from the unfiltered dates table.

Comment: You are write, I did not write my example properly. I edited my post in accordingly ; however, even when using the calculation group with a measure, the output is still incorrect.

Comment: Two additional problems: (1) Your date column is a text data type (2) You are using dim_Dates inside TOPN but expecting behavior like ALL(dim_Dates) or ALLSELECTED(dim_Dates).

Comment: Correct : writing ALL(dim_Dates) in stead of simply dim_Dates inside TOPN solves the problem. You can edit your answer accordingly so that I can accept it as the solution to my problem. Thank you for your help.